# img要素の読み込み完了後に非表示要素を表示したい

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

img要素の読み込み完了を検知し、非表示要素を表示するため、onload=""を使用してCSSの生成を行いたいのですが、いまいち方法が理解できておりません。

```
<style>
  セレクタ {display: none;}
</style>
```

上記のCSSを、onloadを使用して

```
<style>
  セレクタ {display: block;}
</style>
```

に上書きしたいと思っています。

onloadの処理でdisplay:blockを生成する事は可能でしょうか？
知識のある方お手数をお掛けいたしますが、ご教授いただける幸いでございます。

以下は現在のコードでございます。

```css
.main_off {
  display: none;
}
.main_on {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function main_on(){
    // イメージが読み込まれた！
    document.getElementsByTagName('div').className = "main_on";
  }
</script>

<div class='onload-on-img-onload main_off' onload="main_on();">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" />
</div>

<div class='onload-on-img-onload main_off' onload="main_on();">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" />
</div>

<script>
  // ## ユーティリティ ##
  // div をスキャンして画像読み込み後に onload を呼び出すコード
  var divs = $(".onload-on-img-onload");
  divs.each(function (idx, div) {
    var imgs = $(div).find("img");
    var count = imgs.length;
  if (count==0 && div.onload)
    div.onload.call(div, count);
  var loaded = 0;
  imgs.one("load", function (e) {
    loaded++;
    if (loaded === count && div.onload)
        div.onload.call(div, count);
    }).each(function () {
      if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
  });
</script>

<body>
```

上記コードは(div内はかなりフェイクいれています)色々なサンプルを混ぜ合わして作っている為、私自身理解しきれていません。
ですので、まったく手法が変わっても構いませんので、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: やるべきことは CSS の生成ではなく、class の張替えに思えるのですがどうでしょう。そしてやりたいことは「ある非表示の要素の下のimg要素をすべてロードし終わってから、その非表示な要素を表示したい」ということでしょうかね?

Comment: KoRoN 様 ご返答ありがとうございます。
＞＞やるべきことは CSS の生成ではなく、class の張替えに思えるのですがどうでしょう。＜＜これに関しましては、用途は問いません。

Comment: ＞＞ある非表示の要素の下のimg要素をすべてロードし終わってから、その非表示な要素を表示したい＜＜ある非表示ではなく、「要素の下のimg要素をすべてロードし終わってから、その非表示な要素を表示したい」となります。

Answer (score 1):

CSSの評価順を逆手に取って、優先順位の高い位置で、上書きしたいスタイル定義を「再定義」してあげれば良さそうです。

特にbodyタグ内での定義が優先順位として高いので、onloadイベント発火後に、JavaScriptでbodyタグ内にcreateElement("style")してあげて、それに対して上書きしたセレクタに対する新しい定義をinsertRule()で追加してあげれば、おそらくやりたいことは実現できると思います。

Answer (score 1):

以下の様な感じでいいかと思います。

```
<script>
function main_on(el){
    //クラスを付け替える
    $(el).removeClass("main_off").addClass("main_on");
}
</script>
<div class='onload-on-img-onload main_off'>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" />
</div>

<div class='onload-on-img-onload main_off'>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" />
</div>
<script>
function handler(event){
    //渡された親要素の配下のimgが全てcomplete属性が真ならば切り替え処理を呼ぶ
    if($(event.data).hasClass("main_off") && //二重に呼ばれるのを防止する
       $(event.data).find("img").filter(function(index, element) {
         return !element.complete;
       }).length == 0){
           main_on(event.data);
    }
}
//onload-on-img-onload クラスのdiv 配下のimgのonloadイベントにhandlerを割り付ける
$("div.onload-on-img-onload").each(function (idx, div) {
  $(div).find("img").one("load", div, handler);//トップのdivを渡す
});
</script>
```

Comment: ハンドラ付加処理中にロードが終了してしまうと動作しない可能性がありますね。

Answer (score 1):

これでどうですか？
[Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached)さんの回答を参考にしています。
`each`部分はキャッシュの読み込みに対応している部分で、`load`イベントを発火しています。
※BLUEPIXYさんの指摘を受け、画像読み込み完了待ちするように修正しました。

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var loadWaitCount = $("img.loadWait").length;

    $("img.loadWait").one("load", function() {
        loadWaitCount--;
        if (loadWaitCount == 0) {
            $("#main").removeClass("main_off").addClass("main_on");
        }
    }).each(function() {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });

});
```

```css
#main {
  width: 160px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #aaddcc;
}

.main_off {
  display: none;
}

.main_on {
  display: block;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="contents">
  <img class="loadWait" src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" />
  <img class="loadWait" src="http://i.imgur.com/PWSOy.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="main" class="main_off">main contents!</div>
```

余談ですが、質問に書かれているコードが`jQuery`化できていないです。

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div').className = "main_on";
```

は`jQuery`では

```
$('div').addClass('main_on');
```

で良いです。

Answer (score 1):

子孫セレクタを利用すると、シンプルになります。

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .hoge {
        display: none;
      }
      
      .loaded .hoge {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="document.body.classList.add('loaded');">
    <div class="hoge"> Loaded!! </div>
  </body>
</html>
```